# CSS alignment for images larger and smaller images

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hello all
I'm trying to get some images to line up using CSS. So in the Screen Grab I need the smaller tiles 'Password Management' etc to line up to the bigger tiles, ie 'IT Services'. float 'left' was great to aligning up the smaller tiles, but I can't seem to be able to the big and small tiles on the same line.

Code below:

Thanks

```
<style>
.wrapper {
box-sizing: border-box;
height:100%;
background: #ffffff;
text-align: left;
}
.wrapper2 {
box-sizing: border-box;
height:100%;
background: #000fff;
text-align: left;
margin: 2px;
 }
.box {
width: 171px;
height: 152px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin: 2px;
}
.topicImage{
display: inline-block;
border: 0px;
float: left;

}
</style>
<!--<div style="width: 80%; display: table;">-->
<div style="width: 89%; display: table; background: #ffffff;">
<div style="display: table-row">
    <div style="width: 100px; display: table-cell;"><img     
   src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-HubImages/it-services.png" alt="IT Services" 
 class="topicImage"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="box"><a href="/IT/Pages/GIT-Password-Management.aspx" 
      class="topicImage"><img src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-HubImages/password-
       management.png" alt="Helpful information on how to manage and reset 
       your network password"class="topicImage"></a></div>
          <div class="box"><a href="/IT/Pages/GIT-Email-Management.aspx" 
    class="topicImage"><img src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-HubImages/email.png" 
     alt="Helpful information on how to access/manage your email account, 
      how to identify and block unwanted email"class="topicImage"></a></div>
          <div class="box"><a href="/IT/Pages/GIT-Web-Access.aspx" 
          class="topicImage"><img src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-
         HubImages/InternetAccess.png" alt="Overview of the rules on 
          website restrictions and how to request access to a blocked site" 
         class="topicImage"></a></div>
          <div class="box"><a href="/IT/Pages/GIT-Skype-for-Business.aspx" 
          class="topicImage"><img src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-
          HubImages/SkypeforBusiness.png" alt="Click here for tips and  
          hints on how to use Skype for Business" 
          class="topicImage"></a></div>
          <div class="box"><a href="/IT/Documents/Guest%20Wifi%
          20Password.pdf" class="topicImage"><img 
        src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-HubImages/guest-wifi.png"  
      alt="Information on joining the guest WIFI" 
       class="topicImage"></a></div>   
          <div class="box"><a 
          href="\\norgine.lan\netlogon\scripts\AddPrinter.qds" 
          class="topicImage"><img src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-
         HubImages/printer.png" alt="Click here to find and connect to a 
         printer at your current location" 
          class="topicImage"></a></div>              
          <div class="box"><a href="/IT/Pages/GIT-Microsoft-Home-Use-
           Program.aspx" class="topicImage"><img src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-
          HubImages/home-use.png" alt="How to purchase Microsoft Office 
          Professional at a discounted price" class="topicImage"></a></div>
          <div class="box"><a  
           href="file://norgine.lan/NETLOGON/UserDUA.hta" 
           class="topicImage"><img src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-
            HubImages/Updatemydetails.png" alt="Click there to update your 
            profile information" class="topicImage"></a></div>
          <div class="box"><a href="http://sqm.norgine.com/SpamConsole/" 
            class="topicImage"><img src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT- 
            HubImages/ManageSpamEmail.png" alt="Click here to manage and 
            release blocked emails"class="topicImage"></a></div>
          <div class="box"><a
          href="http://cloud.norgine.com/Lists/SiteRequests/NewForm.aspx
            Source=http%3A%2F%2Fcloud%2Enorgine%2Ecom"   
     class="topicImage"><img src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT- 
     HubImages/RequestSharePointSite.png" alt="Click here to raise a 
      request to create a new SharePoint site" class="topicImage"></a></div>
          <div class="box"><a 
     href="http://apps.norgine.com/sites/CSP/eGSOP/_layouts/WordViewer.aspx?
     id=/sites/CSP/eGSOP/Released%20Forms%20and%20Templates/TP-
     0276.dotx&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fapps%2Enorgine%2Ecom%2Fsites%2FCSP%
     2FeGSOP%2FReleased%2520Forms%2520and%2520Templates%2FForms%2FOwner   
     2520SiteFunction%2Easpx%3FGroupString%3D%253B%2523Harefield%2520%2528 
     252B%2520Global%2520Functions%2529%253B%2523IT%253B%2523
      26IsGroupRender%3DTRUE&DefaultItemOpen=1 " class="topicImage"><img
     src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-HubImages/Requestdomainname.png" 
    alt="Clickhere to view Norgines domain repository, request new or 
     retire domains" class="topicImage"></a></div>
          <div class="box"><a href="  " class="topicImage"><img 
    src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-HubImages/ITSecurityForm.png" alt="Click   
   here to complete and print the IT Security form" 
   class="topicImage"></a></div>
          <div class="box"><a href="/IT/Documents/System%20Register.pdf" 
     class="topicImage"><img src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-
     HubImages/ServiceCatalogue.png" alt="Click here for a list of 
     information and contact details for business systems and application" 
     class="topicImage"></a></div>
          <div class="box"><a href=" " class="topicImage"><img   
  src="/IT/SiteAssets/KnowIT-HubImages/MobilePhones.PNG" alt="Coming soon" 
   class="topicImage"></a></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share an example (a sample image) of what you are expecting in the final outcome? Or is it something like this http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/07-10tiles.jpg ? [OR] like this http://file.mrbool.com/mrbool/articles/JoelRodrigues/MetroMenuStyle/MenuMetroHTML2.jpg ?

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox to resolve this problem

You can see this link A Complete Guide to Flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks. I added .container {
flex-direction:row;

}

Comment: Thanks, I added: .container {
flex-direction:row;

} into the CSS but it doesn't do anything?

Comment: you need to give **display:flex;** with **flex-direction:row**

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions are:

1. Get rid of inline styles.
2. Here is simplified version of your code with my adjustments:

```css
.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.box, .topicImage {
  background-color: #0078d7;
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.topicImage{
  width: 304px;
  height: 304px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div style="float: left;"><div class="topicImage"></div></div>
    <div>
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--              
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated version, fixed width:

```css
.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1078px;
}

.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.box, .topicImage {
  background-color: #0078d7;
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.topicImage{
  width: 304px;
  height: 304px;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="topicImage"></div>
    <div>
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--              
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div><!--
          --><div class="box"></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Mike. How would I restrict the number of small boxes on one line? Ideally I'd like 7 on each line.

Comment: @Dazza by adjusting the main div's width.

Comment: Also when I add the images it does throw out the formatting

Comment: Cheers. Still looking at it and can't get it to work, but will take another look tomorrow